# Какой знак нужен, тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

«Почему это так важно —/, правильно ставить знаки препинания?»

Мне кажется, что тире, но я не могу это обосновать.
Такая структура предложения имеет какое-то специальное название?

Comment: На ресурсе не приветствуются вопросы-опросы, не имеющие однозначного объективного ответа

Comment: @behemothus, 1) а как узнать заранее, что вопрос про пунктуацию с конкретным примером не имеет однозначного ответа? 2) из вашего ответа можно сделать вывод, что запятая здесь тоже легитимна. Это так?

Comment: 1) У вас вопрос про пунктуацию или про мнение? Если про пунктуацию, то проблем нет. Только сформулируйте конкретнее.  Если про субъективное мнение, какой знак ставить, то это уже "неформат"  2) Я не писал *ответа*. Это комментарий.

Comment: @behemothus, я думала, что если вставить в название темы два знака препинания через наклонную черту (—/,), то будет понятно, что я спрашиваю, какой знак выбрать. Теперь я поняла, как правильно спрашивать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом случае ставится тире: Почему **это** так важно — правильно ставить знаки препинания?

Это тема обособления пояснительных членов предложения. В данном случае местоимение "это" является подлежащим, а его значение раскрывает обособленный оборот на основе инфинитива, который выполняет функцию второго подлежащего, поясняющего первое.

Вообще говоря, пояснительные члены предложения обособляются всегда, но необходимо выбрать нужный знак - запятые или тире.

**Из Правил Лопатина:**

§ 82. При наличии слов, обязательно требующих раскрытия (пояснения) значения, ставится тире: Он всеми силами души всегда желал **одного** — быть вполне хорошим (Л. Т.); Цель, поставленная перед отрядом, была **одна** — до рассвета дойти до леса; Байкал славен и свят **другим** — своей чудесной, животворной силой (Расп.). В таких предложениях тире замещает пропущенный пояснительный союз (можно вставить а именно).